# Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id' on mongoose/mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using `findOneAndUpdate` with **upsert** set **true** if the model was found, update it with **updateCompany** else create a new one

```
const company = req.body.company_id
const updatedCompany = {
      name: payload.company_name,
      billing_address: payload.billing_address,
      billing_email: payload.billing_email
    }
const thecompany = await Company.findOneAndUpdate({_id: company}, updatedCompany, { upsert: true, new: true }).lean().exec();
console.log(thecompany)
```

I'm getting this error `MongoError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'`

Comment: Yes because you are modifiying the _id , it's the ObjectId that mongodb generate it so you can just change "_id" by your "company_id" , don"t change_id generate by mongo

Comment: I ran into the problem for a different reason; I assigned to updatedCompany a Company object rather than a plain dictionary. Switching to a plain dictionary fixed the code in my case. Your code looks alright to me ...